# Foxpro, how to get access to form from menu buttons?

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

For example some simple form

```
define class myf as form
    add object text1 as textbox
    procedure init
        do G:\mymenu.mpr with thisform
    endproc
enddefine
```

and contents of mymeny.mpr file:

```
parameters f
Define Menu menubar in (m.f.Name) Bar
Define Pad qrs of menubar prompt "Queries"
ON SELECTION pad qrs OF menubar do dosth

procedure dosth
    ???.text1.value = "sample"
endproc
```

how can i refer to form myf from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Kassie has an option of _screen.ActiveForm, there's no guarantee that will always be available.  You can however, always add a custom property to the _Screen object and set it to that of your form.  Then, you can always refer to it even if it is not the "Active" form and want to bring focus TO it...

```
define class myf as form
    add object text1 as textbox
    procedure init
        if NOT PEMSTATUS( _Screen, "oMyForm", 5 )
           _Screen.AddProperty( "oMyForm" )
        endif 
        _Screen.oMyForm = this

        do G:\mymenu.mpr 
    endproc
enddefine
```

then, in the menu program, no need to require the parameter, you can just use the now publicly visible property attached to the _Screen object and go from that

```
Define Menu menubar in (_Screen.oMyForm.Name) Bar
Define Pad qrs of menubar prompt "Queries"
ON SELECTION pad qrs OF menubar do dosth

procedure dosth
    _Screen.oMyForm.text1.Value = "sample"
endproc
```

Answer (score 0):

As one of possible solutions I've found is to use _screen.ActiveForm

```
_screen.ActiveForm.text1.value
```